# How can I return the Woocommerce product gallery on a single page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to get the product gallery on my landing page, without loading all the other data like description and price etc. with it. So I want the product gallery to look exactly the same on the landing pages, without the rest.

I'm trying to create a shortcode for this, so I can easily insert it based on the product ID, for example. Only I'm not getting there at all.

It needs to be something like this, but this function only outputs the individual product images, not the entire gallery (with styling).

```
function product_gallery( $atts ) {

    if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_gallery_image_html' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $product = wc_get_product( 'ID' );

    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

    if ( $attachment_ids && $product->get_image_id() ) {
        foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', wc_get_gallery_image_html( $attachment_id ), $attachment_id );
        }
    }

}

add_shortcode('product_gallery', 'product_gallery' );
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can build this, or does anyone know a plugin I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `woocommerce-product-gallery` class container in your code. and you'll need to enqueue `single-product`JS where all the JS code is available for Single product gallery. You will get CSS issues because I think CSS is only applied on single product page, you'll have to test it, I am unsure about css.